# Any way to change the Chip background color from MDCChipField without Material Theming in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, material-components-ios

Added Chips from MDCChipView()

```
let chipField = MDCChipField()
let chipView = MDCChipView()

chipView.titleLabel.text = "text"
chipField.addChip(chipView)
```

Comment: chipField.backgroundColor = .white

Comment: This way change background color but not the Chip background color. Thanks for your help

Comment: [https://material.io/develop/ios/components/chips/api-docs/Classes/MDCChipView.html]

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can change chip view background color:

```
chipView.setBackgroundColor(.green, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```